# Create ZIP file in php , windows

Tags: php, apache, zip, 7zip

I have to create a zip file using php. The files are located in a directory of my web server. 
I have to add these files ( dynamically ) and make a zip file.

Working perfect in php with small files but when I tried to make zip using files greater than 200 MB I will take more time to create zip.

So is there is any way to make a zip file using windows system command, which can run through PHP ? So that we can create zip files easily and quickly with out memory loss .

Please help

Comment: And what happens if you need to add 20 files, 2 GB each? Just because you change the method of creating a zip file, it won't be created quicker (or at least significantly quicker).  If you have large files to zip, then you'll just have to take the performance hit - no two ways around it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to implement a queue of some kind, perhaps in your database. You enqueue zip operations, while on the background a cron job of some kind does the zipping, and notifies your queue when it's finished.

This won't decrease processing time, but since zipping is a CPU and I/O heavy operation, it probably can't be sped up much. Using this technique you don't have to let your user wait until zipping is done, you could for example simply send an e-mail (with the link to the created zip file) when it's done.

Comment: thanks for your reply and can you help me a little how to make zip using dynamic files from php ?

Comment: @ramesh there is no such thing as 'dynamic files', so I don't know what you mean. Using [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) you can add files from disk, and data from memory to the zip archive.

Comment: okey .. that what I meant actually. .. But how to create a zip from a operation like cron job ? I mean run in background ?

Comment: @ramesh you can run a PHP script from a cron job, so using [ZipArchive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) you can do whatever you like.